# How to merge columns in temporary table while inserting data from a SubQuery in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a temp table #TestData as below where data is inserted using sub-query

```
Id      Amount         Ccy    Description
2012    2373350.000    INR    test1
2012    2321030.000    INR    test12
2014    2350.000       INR    test4
2014    30.000         USD    test5
2014    130.000        USD    test6
```

code updated : using stuff and group by to concatenate strings hoever getting error **invalid object Tmpta**

```
      INSERT  INTO #TestData

       -- SELECT  Tmpta.Id,Tmpta.Amount,Tmpta.Ccy,tmpta.Description
     SELECT  Tmpta.Id ,
                    STUFF(( SELECT  ',' + CAST(B.[Amount] AS VARCHAR(20))
                            FROM    Tmpta B
                            WHERE   B.id = Tmpta.id
                            ORDER BY B.[Amount]
                          FOR
                            XML PATH('')
                          ), 1, 1, '') AS Amount ,
                    STUFF(( SELECT  ',' + B.[cur]
                            FROM    Tmpta B
                            WHERE   B.id = Tmpta.id
                            ORDER BY B.[cur]
                          FOR
                            XML PATH('')
                          ), 1, 1, '') AS Ccy ,
                    STUFF(( SELECT  ',' + B.[Description]
                            FROM    Tmpta B
                            WHERE   B.id = Tmpta.id
                            ORDER BY B.[Description]
                          FOR
                            XML PATH('')
                          ), 1, 1, '') AS Description
         FROM    ( SELECT SubQuery
                  ) Tmpta              

         WHERE   tmpta.Id in (2012,2014)
         group by Tmpta.id
```

I want to merge data as below :

```
Id      Amount                         Ccy          Description
2012    2373350.000,2321030.000        INR,INR      test1,test12
2014    2350.000,30.000,130.000        INR,USD,USD  test4,test5,test6
```

any idea how we can achieve this?

Please help.
Thanks!

Comment: Upgrade your version of SQL Server and use `string_agg()`.

Comment: Using `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH`. There's plenty of examples of how to generate a delimited list in SQL Server. [site:stackoverflow.com create comma delimited list SQL server](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+create+comma+delimited+list+SQL+server)

Comment: Personally, however, I would suggest avoiding this type of data. This makes it so that things like ordinal position has meaning, and functions like `STRING_SPLIT` don't support that. Stick to keeping your data normalised.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server)

Comment: @MarcGuillot . No i have edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use subquery then you can to put that data into the temp table and use that table in the query except using a subquery

DROP TABLE #Tmpta

SELECT ID,Amount,cur,Description 
INTO #Tmpta
from data A

SELECT  #Tmpta.Id ,
                    STUFF(( SELECT  ',' + CAST(B.[Amount] AS VARCHAR(20))
                            FROM    #Tmpta B
                            WHERE   B.id = #Tmpta.id
                            ORDER BY B.[Amount]
                          FOR
                            XML PATH('')
                          ), 1, 1, '') AS Amount ,
                    STUFF(( SELECT  ',' + B.[cur]
                            FROM    #Tmpta B
                            WHERE   B.id = #Tmpta.id
                            ORDER BY B.[cur]
                          FOR
                            XML PATH('')
                          ), 1, 1, '') AS Ccy ,
                    STUFF(( SELECT  ',' + B.[Description]
                            FROM    #Tmpta B
                            WHERE   B.id = #Tmpta.id
                            ORDER BY B.[Description]
                          FOR
                            XML PATH('')
                          ), 1, 1, '') AS Description
         FROM    #Tmpta

```
     WHERE   #Tmpta.Id in (2012,2014)
     group by #Tmpta.id
```

Comment: i was trying it however tmpta which is created with Select sub query is not recognizable in STUFF select.it saying invalid object tmpta

Comment: why you use FROM    ( SELECT SubQuery) Tmpta  you can only use FROM Tmpta

Comment: Because it has several filter criteria and data get fetched from different tables

Answer (score 0):

try below query

```
    SELECT
    ID,  string_agg(Amount,',') As Amount, string_agg(ccy,',') as CCY, string_agg(description, ',')  
FROM
    <table name>
GROUP BY
    ID;
```

Comment: The OP has tagged [tag:sql-server-2012]. `STRING_AGG` was added in SQL Server 2017.